# Draw a based line in Google line chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I working with Google line chart I want to draw a based line but I don't know how should I do that for example I want to draw line in 2004 between 400 and 600 how should I do that
here Google Sample:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure from your question exactly what it is you want to do, can you add an image showing what you want?

Comment: sorry I can't put picture becaues I am new here and I don't have enough reputation but I can be more clear I want A line perpendicular to the graph for example I want to draw a line in 2004 between 400 and 600 imagein that horizontal axis is x and the vertical axis is y I want a line that that first of that is x=2004 and y=400 and the end of that is x=2004 and y=600 you I don't want to change x just y change can you get it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a few different ways, depending on exactly what you want to achieve.  The easiest way is to use "interval" role columns:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', {role: 'interval', type: 'number'}, {role: 'interval', type: 'number'}],
        ['2004', 1000, 400, 400, 600],
        ['2005', 1170, 460, null, null],
        ['2006', 660, 1120, null, null],
        ['2007', 1030, 540, null, null]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

There is quite a bit of customization you can do with intervals, see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/intervals).

Another way is to add a new series of data for this line, change the data type of the first column from "string" to "number", and add multiple rows of data with the same x-values, eg:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'vertical lines'],
        [2004, 1000, 400, 400],
        [2004, null, null, 600],
        [2005, 1170, 460, null],
        [2006, 660, 1120, null],
        [2007, 1030, 540, null]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        interpolateNulls: true, // this prevents your other lines from breaking
        series: {
            2: {
                // these options control your new series for the vertical lines
                visibleInLegend: false, // hide from the legend
                enableInteractivity: false // make the line non-interactive
                color: '#9055a6' // set the color of the line
                // etc...
            }
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: but none of them helped I just need this vertical lines in my chart and I want the first and last of them show when clicked them like the other part of chart

Comment: If you want to be able to click on them like the other line series, use the second method, but don't set the `enableInteractivity` option in the `series` options - I put those there just as examples of what you can do if you needed this line to be different from the others.